# biblatex: Abbreviating cyrillic authors' names with firstinits option

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, cyrillic

When setting the bibliography with `biblatex` using the `authoryear-comp` style and option `firstinits=true` the authors' first names in the references are not correctly displayed when using cyrillic names.

The XeTeX file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xunicode,fontspec,xltxtra,setspace}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true,uniquename=init,backend=biber,maxnames=2]{biblatex}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\begin{document}
\parencite{belyj1913} , \parencite{belyj1919}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and bibliography.bib

```
@book{belyj1913,
    Address = {Москва},
    Author = {Андрей Белый},
    Publisher = {Наука},
    Title = {Петербург},
    Year = {1981}}

@book{belyj1919,
    Address = {München},
    Author = {Andrej Bjäly},
    Publisher = {Georg Müller},
    Title = {Petersburg},
    Year = {1919}}
```

produce

> Bjäly, A. (1919). *Petersburg.* München: Georg Müller.
>
> Белый, �. (1981). *Петербург.* Москва: Наука.

[image]

Setting, however, `firstinits=false` (which is what I **don't** want) works:

> Bjäly, Andrej (1919). *Petersburg.* München: Georg Müller.
>
> Белый, Андрей (1981). *Петербург.* Москва: Наука.

[image]

Is there a way to correctly print the abbreviated cyrillic "А."?

Additionaly log output with `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2011/05/30 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (type area)
xunicode.sty    2010/11/06 v0.96 provides access to latin accents and many other characters in Unicode lower plane
fontspec.sty    2011/02/26 v2.1f Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2011/08/28 v2678 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2011/08/10 v2538 L3 Experimental namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2011/08/13 v2558 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
l3basics.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2011/08/11 v2545 L3 Experimental argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental token lists
   l3seq.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2011/08/26 v2666 L3 Experimental integers
 l3quark.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental quarks
   l3prg.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental control structures
 l3clist.sty    2011/08/26 v2666 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental property lists
   l3msg.sty    2011/08/16 v2601 L3 Experimental messages
    l3io.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental input-output operations
  l3file.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental file operations
  l3skip.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental dimensions and skips
   l3box.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental boxes
  l3keys.sty    2011/08/28 v2677 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2011/08/25 v2665 L3 Experimental floating-point operations
l3luatex.sty    2011/08/18 v2617 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3coffins.sty    2011/08/18 v2624 L3 Experimental coffin code layer
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  l3toks.sty    2011/08/27 v2670 L3 Experimental token registers
  xparse.sty    2011/08/28 v2678 L3 Experimental document command parser
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
fontspec-patches.sty    2011/02/26 v2.1f Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
fontspec.cfg
 xltxtra.sty    2010/09/20 v0.5e Improvements for the "XeLaTeX" format
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
realscripts.sty    2010/09/30 v0.3 Access OpenType subscripts and superscripts
metalogo.sty    2010/05/29 v0.12 Extended TeX logo macros
setspace.sty    2000/12/01 6.7 Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package
biblatex.sty    2011/11/13 v1.7 programmable bibliographies
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
blx-compat.def    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex generic compatibility
biblatex.def    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex generic definitions
standard.bbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex bibliography style
authoryear.bbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex bibliography style
authoryear-comp.bbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex bibliography style
authoryear-comp.cbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex citation style
biblatex.cfg    
 english.lbx    2011/11/13 v1.7 biblatex localization
DA_XeTeX_Test.bbl
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: I don't get anything strange. Can you add the part in the log file that you get after adding `\listfiles`?

Comment: @egreg The author's first name is not abbreviated correctly. Instead a diamond with questionmark is created, visibly on bitmap. I added the output of `\listfiles` above.

Comment: @F.Neukamm You have quite a strange distribution (a very old `graphicx.sty`, for instance) and outdated `expl3` files. What I can say is that the bbl has the UTF-8 pair `<D0><90>` (which corresponds to a cyrillic capital A, U+0410).

Comment: @egreg Checked on the distribution (MacTeX) again: it's now up to date (`graphicx.sty` still dated to 1999 since the most recent release was back then). But still no luck with the cyrillic _A_. When using Times New Roman font the diamond sign is omitted, a blank character is printed.

Comment: What's the version of Biber? `biber -v` from the Terminal

Comment: `biber`'s version is 0.9.8.

Comment: Are you using PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? This works fine for me with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX which is seems you are using due to fontspec. You probably don't need xunicode - it also works for me without this. It's also important to know how your .bib file and .tex file are encoded - both UTF-8? Your xunicode is a bit old too, try without it.

Comment: @PLK I am using `XeLaTeX`. Meanwhile, I updated my whole distribution. But even without `xunicode` I didn't succeed. Both the .tex and the .bib file are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: In wonder if this is a font issue. I just tried it again on another machine and I have no problems but I'm using the GNU unifont font as I don't have the Linux Libertine fonts:
`\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{unifont}`

Comment: That would be the case if you would be using bibtex.exe or bibtex8.exe as backend and your bib file is in Unicode. Neither bibtex.exe or bibtex8.exe can cut full name to abbreviation in Unicode. However biber.exe is expected to produce fine result. could you check biber's log?