# Biblatex, biber and non-latin (cyrillic) UTF-8 names part II

Tags: biblatex, unicode, biber, cyrillic

I was looking for an example using `biblatex`, `biber` and mixed Latin/Greek/Cyrillic document; I found [biblatex biber non-latin (cyrillic) UTF-8 names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74321/biblatex-biber-non-latin-cyrillic-utf-8-names) and [biblatex: Abbreviating cyrillic authors' names with firstinits option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44867/biblatex-abbreviating-cyrillic-authors-names-with-firstinits-option), but neither of them are conclusive (and are closed). So, I came up with an MWE (below) which compiles with `pdflatex test.tex; biber test; pdflatex test.tex; pdflatex test.tex` (using TexLive 2014), and produces this:

[image: /tmp/test.png]

Mostly it looks as it should - my questions are:

- Is this the correct way to use cyrillic names/titles with biblatex/biber? (that is, with `\foreignlanguage`?)
- Like in the above post, the cyrillic name is not abbreviated, while the latin one is. How could I get them both to abbreviate?

EDIT: The reason for not abbreviating can be seen in the `.bbl` file:

```
\name{author}{1}{}{%
  {{hash=3bd6100cde97ee45844a484f7fc7612b}{Goethe}{G\bibinitperiod}{Johann\bibnamedelima Wolfgang}{J\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim W\bibinitperiod}{von}{v\bibinitperiod}{}{}}%
...
\name{author}{1}{}{%
  {{hash=c78e01570c60a06ba7419ac38e11ab99}{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Фёдор\bibnamedelimb Михайлович\bibnamedelimb Достоевский}}{\\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}{}{}}%
```

Seemingly, `biblatex`/`biber` is smart enough to see through the `\foreignlanguage` to insert a `\bibnamedelimb` also for the cyrillic name, but somehow, doesn't fill all the fields (in particular, those containing the abbreviations). If I try to hack manually, and insert by analogy with the latin name, for `labelname` and `author`, this instead:

```
    {{hash=c78e01570c60a06ba7419ac38e11ab99}{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Достоевский}}{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Д\bibinitperiod}}{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Фёдор\bibnamedelima Михайлович}}{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Ф\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim М\bibinitperiod}}{}{}{}{}}%
```

... then abbreviating works - but clearly, I wouldn't want to do this manually for each cyrillic entry, so the question can be posed: can I somehow coax `biber` to produce this automatically, maybe by entering some commands in the `.bib` file?

EDIT2: I also tried wrapping each author name word in foreignlanguage in the .bib file:

```
author={\foreignlanguage{russian}{Фёдор} \foreignlanguage{russian}{Михайлович} \foreignlanguage{russian}{Достоевский}},
```

... this doesn't work at all (there is no abbreviation, and in fact, some words are skipped in the final output).

EDIT3: As @egreg pointed out in comments (single object), I tried removing the `\foreignlanguage` for the author name, and write directly in UTF-8:

```
author={Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский},
```

... and now this splits name components correctly in the `.bbl` file:

```
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=e3c9a72252d468ac324a38026797e091}{Достоевский}{Д\bibinitperiod}{Фёдор\bibnamedelima Михайлович}{Ф\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim М\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
```

... but then, when `pdflatex` is ran for the second time, it crashes with:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \CYRF unavailable in encoding T1.
```

... so apparently, font encoding switch is still needed.

---

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{von1841faust,
  title={Faust: Eine Tragödie. Erster Theil},
  author={Johann Wolfgang von Goethe},
  url={http://books.google.dk/books?id=zF8-AAAAYAAJ},
  year={1841},
  publisher={Hermann Passarge}
}

% see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215447/using-cyrillic-with-tex-gyre-pagella-and-pdflatex
% if fonts are properly set-up, there's no need for separate \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont, as in:
%   title={\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont \foreignlanguage{russian}{Двойник}},
% else - with or without \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont:
% ! LaTeX Error: Command \CYRD unavailable in encoding T1.
% with \foreignlanguage and \fontencoding{T2A}:
% LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/qpl/m/n' undefined
% (Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 48.
% kpathsea: Running mktexmf larm1000
% ! I can't find file `larm1000'.
% <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000
% mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1000' failed to make larm1000.tfm.
% ! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

@book{dostoevskij2014dvoinik,
  title={\foreignlanguage{russian}{Двойник}},
  author={\foreignlanguage{russian}{Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский}},
  isbn={9785000640227},
  url={http://books.google.dk/books?id=OR7BAQAAQBAJ},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Aegitas}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc} % before babel!
\usepackage[russian,greek,english]{babel} % tlmgr install babel-russian

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{paratype} % tlmgr install paratype
\usepackage{tgpagella}

% T2A for cyrillic - paratype
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{PTSerif-TLF}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[%
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true,
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=nyt, % "Sort by name, year, title."
  %sorting=none, % "Do not sort at all. All entries are processed in citation order." (order of appearance)
  bibencoding=utf8,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

From \si{\mega\ohm} to \si{\micro\watt} -- consider "Faust" \cite{von1841faust}, which is in (extended) Latin script; or "\foreignlanguage{russian}{Двойник}" \cite{dostoevskij2014dvoinik}, which is in Cyrillic script.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The author's name can't be abbreviated, because it's a single object, with the syntax you're using.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, it looks like that to me too, especially after the latest edit, where I've tried to wrap each word in the author name in `.bib` with `\foreignlanguage`... Is there an alternative syntax that could be used? I looked up "foreign" in the `biblatex` manual, but that didn't tell me much.. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `\foreignlanguage` in the `.bib` file. Use biblatex option `autolang=other` instead. It automatically wraps bib entries in the `otherlanguage` environment. For this to work you also need `langid` fields in the `.bib` file.

This is your MWE corrected (I removed the font setup, it doesn't work on my machine for some reason --- but I guess it's a different problem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{von1841faust,
  title={Faust: Eine Tragödie. Erster Theil},
  author={Johann Wolfgang von Goethe},
  url={http://books.google.dk/books?id=zF8-AAAAYAAJ},
  year={1841},
  publisher={Hermann Passarge},
  langid={german},
}

@book{dostoevskij2014dvoinik,
  title={Двойник},
  author={Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский},
  isbn={9785000640227},
  url={http://books.google.dk/books?id=OR7BAQAAQBAJ},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Aegitas},
  langid={russian},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % before babel!
\usepackage[russian,greek,german,english]{babel} % tlmgr install babel-russian

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[%
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true,
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=nyt, % "Sort by name, year, title."
  %sorting=none, % "Do not sort at all. All entries are processed in citation order." (order of appearance)
  bibencoding=utf8,
  backend=biber,
  language=auto,    % get main language from babel
  autolang=other,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

From \si{\mega\ohm} to \si{\micro\watt} -- consider "Faust" \cite{von1841faust}, which is in (extended) Latin script; or "\foreignlanguage{russian}{Двойник}" \cite{dostoevskij2014dvoinik}, which is in Cyrillic script.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: test.png]

Comment: Many thanks for that, @OlegDomanov; in the meantime, I also found `langid`, which works only with `autolang=other` (its default is `none`); but with my font setup, I got the problem that `isbn`, which is in smallcaps, gets rendered in Greek (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215544/remapping-fonts-between-different-encodings). Still, great to see an example that works fine with Computer Modern. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: My pleasure))   Yes, this the font problem I ran into. Probably it's better to use `xetex` here.

Comment: I can't get this MWE to work. In the output file, all cyrillic characters are omitted. Any idea on how to fix this? Is it a font problem?

Comment: It's difficult to say. Should work out of the box. It seems smth is wrong with your TeX installation. Or maybe your way to do the compilation. Or smth else.