# Remapping fonts between different encodings?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215447/using-cyrillic-with-tex-gyre-pagella-and-pdflatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc} % before babel!
\usepackage[russian,greek,english]{babel} % tlmgr install babel-russian

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{paratype} % tlmgr install paratype
\usepackage{tgpagella}

% T2A for cyrillic - paratype
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{PTSerif-TLF}


\begin{document}

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
Testing: \textsc{Small-caps Test!}

\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont
Testing: \textsc{Small-caps Test!}

\end{document}
```

When building this, it will fail with:

```
! No declaration for shape T2A/PTSerif-TLF/m/sc.
sub@sfcnt ...e forspace shapespace mandatory@arg }
                                                  error@fontshape else #1{Fo...
l.23 Testing: \textsc{Small-caps Test!}
```

... but you can press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> here, and `pdflatex` will complete, producing this:

[image: test.png]

So this is the thing: how can I tell Latex, that once it encounter small caps (e.g. `\scshape`) in T2A font encoding (which here uses the `paratype`'s `PTSerif` font), that it should instead use the `tgpagella` font in the T1 encoding (for the small caps only)? I was trying with this in the preamble:

```
\sbox0{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont \scshape X}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{PTSerif-TLF}{m}{sc}{<-> qpl}{} % nope
```

... but that doesn't seem to work. Is this kind of mapping between fonts in different font encodings possible at all?

Comment: You could tell it to use the upright shape from PTSerif-TLF. But I don't think you can tell it to automatically substitute something in a different encoding.